# Converting a Gray-Scale Array to a FloatingPoint-Array

Tags: julia, tiff, geotiff

I am trying to read a .tif-file in julia as a Floating Point Array. With the **FileIO** & **ImageMagick**-Package I am able to do this, but the Array that I get is of the Type  `Array{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}`.

I can convert this FixedPoint-Array to Float32-Array by multiplying it with 255 (because UInt8), but I am looking for a function to do this for any type of FixedPointNumber (i.e. `reinterpret()` or `convert()`).

```
using FileIO
# Load the tif
obj = load("test.tif");
typeof(obj)
# Convert to Float32-Array
objNew = real.(obj) .* 255
typeof(objNew)
```

The output is

```
julia> using FileIO

julia> obj = load("test.tif");

julia> typeof(obj)
Array{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}

julia> objNew = real.(obj) .* 255;

julia> typeof(objNew)
Array{Float32,2}
```

I have been looking in the docs quite a while and have not found the function with which to convert a given FixedPoint-Array to a FloatingPont-Array without multiplying it with the maximum value of the Integer type.

Thanks for any help.

**edit**:
I made [a small gist](https://gist.github.com/georgeblck/bf57c2f40cd10b5b46825b6219e228b6) to see if the solution by Michael works, and it does. Thanks!

*Note*:I don't know why, but the `real.(obj) .* 255`-code does not work (see the gist).

Comment: If it's any help, this calculates `255.0` from `obj`: `2.0^FixedPointNumbers.nbitsfrac(typeof(real(first(obj))))-1.‌​0`

Comment: you can use `reinterpret(UInt8, obj) |> Array{Float32}` if the type(e.g. `UInt8`) is known, which is often the case. It's worth noting that this type depends on your image file format, and "FileIO" may read the image with a wrong default type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just `Float32.()`?

```
using ColorTypes
a = Gray.(convert.(Normed{UInt8,8}, rand(5,6)));
typeof(a)
#Array{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}
Float32.(a)
```

Comment: Nice! :)  (+ `using  ColorTypes` for working example)

Comment: This works, thank you.
I made a gist-notebook to check your code and found out that the way listed in my question (`real.(obj).*255`) **does not** work

Comment: See below for an explanation about multiplication by 255.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is indeed the one given by Michael, just use `Float32.(a)` (for grayscale). Another alternative is `channelview(a)`, which generally performs channel separation thus also stripping the color information from the array. In the latter case you won't get a `Float32` array, because your image is stored with 8 bits per pixel, instead you'll get an `N0f8` (= `FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}`). You can read about those numbers [here](http://juliaimages.github.io/latest/arrays_colors.html).

Your instinct to multiply by 255 is natural, given how other image-processing frameworks work, but Julia has made some effort to be consistent about "meaning" in ways that are worth taking a moment to think about. For example, in another programming language just changing the numerical precision of an array:

```
img = uint8(255*rand(10, 10, 3));   % an 8-bit per color channel image
figure; image(img)
imgd = double(img);   % convert to double-precision, but don't change the values
figure; image(imgd)
```

produces the following surprising result:
[image: 8bit version]
[image: double version]

That second "all white" image represents saturation. In this other language, "5" means two completely different things depending on whether it's stored in memory as a `UInt8` vs a `Float64`. I think it's fair to say that under any normal circumstances, a user of a numerical library would call this a bug, and a very serious one at that, yet somehow many of us have grown to accept this in the context of image processing.

These new types arise because in Julia we've gone to the effort to implement new numerical types (FixedPointNumbers) that act like fractional values (e.g., between 0 and 1) but are stored internally with the same bit pattern as the "corresponding" `UInt8` (the one you get by multiplying by 255). This allows us to work with 8-bit data and yet allow values to always be interpreted on a consistent scale (0.0=black, 1.0=white).